Populated options on select apear black at first but after changing tabs it shows okay
I have a select component like this
<template>
  <div class="newsletter-launcher">
    <h2>Select a Newsletter to Launch</h2>
    <select v-model="selectedNewsletter" class="newsletter-select">
      <option v-for="(newsletter, index) in newsletters" :key="index" :value="newsletter.name">
        {{ newsletter.name }} ({{ newsletter.recipients }} recipients)
      </option>
    </select>
    <button @click="launchNewsletter" class="launch-button">Launch Newsletter</button>
    <p v-if="launchMessage" :class="['launch-message', { 'error-message': isError }]">
      {{ launchMessage }}
    </p>
  </div>
</template>

It is populated on the  like this:
setup() {
  const newsletterStore = useNewsletterStore()
  const { newsletters } = newsletterStore

  onMounted(async () => {
    await newsletterStore.fetchNewsletters()
  })
  return {
    newsletters
  }
}

Also the newsletters variable is populated through the Pinia store:
export const useNewsletterStore = defineStore('newsletter', {
  state: (): NewsletterState => ({
    newsletters: []
  }),
  actions: {
    async fetchNewsletters() {
      try {
        const request_url = apiUrl + '/newsletters'
        const response = await axios.get<Newsletter[]>(apiUrl + '/newsletters', {
          headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + apiToken }
        })
        this.newsletters = response.data
        console.log(request_url)
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching newsletters:', error)
      }
    }
  }
})

When I try to select an option it shows no options and just black but after I change tabs (the blue texts on the top) and go back again to the launch it shows now the correct options
Before

After tabbing


Don't use index for :key. Otherwise, the rest looks fine so far. What do you see in your devtools, network tab? Any errors in the browser console? Is there anything weird if you inspect the state of the component with your Vue devtools? What is launchNewsletter doing exactly, is it relevant?

When I inspect with the devtoolls the "newsletters" object says reactive when its black and after I tab in and out it now shows populated with the options. Is the component rendering before the call gets done?

yes, setup won't wait for your api call so it's rendering before the data is returned. I agree the only real issue I'm seeing is the key shouldn't be index. When you purposefully render an empty list is there a black bar? that might be the whole issue

Do you have a [repro]?

Okay so I figured it out, not entirely sure why, but it was due to how I was populating the newsletter with the store. I replaced this line:
 const { newsletters } = newsletterStore

for
const newsletters = computed(() => newsletterStore.newsletters)

